Is there a way to check which SA key has been used by a service account for a request?
Background: I deployed a 2nd generation Node.js function in GCP specifying the service account in the HttpsOptions object, without specifying anything else.
Is there a way to check which service account key has been used for a requests made by this function?
I can see that a number of keys have been generated and disabled since the deployment of the function and, in some occasions, keys are active at the same time.

What do you mean with API key? I doubt thats the correct term for what you are talking about, can you at least add your code so there's something to go on.

My bad... I edited the question. The keys that I'm trying to check are the service account keys

It isn't currently possible to  display the full service account key for each Cloud Function request There is also a feature request to determine exactly when a Service Account key was used, along with the date and time of usage. However, you can do the following:
You can use Cloud Monitoring metrics to monitor service account or service account key usage.

Service accounts and service account keys appear in these metrics if they are used to call any Google API, including APIs that are not part of Google Cloud. The metrics include both successful and failed API calls.
Service account keys also appear in these metrics if a system lists the keys while attempting to authenticate a request, even if the system doesn't use the key to authenticate the request. This behavior is most common when using signed URLs for Cloud Storage or when authenticating to third-party applications. As a result it is possible to see usage metrics for keys that have not been used for authentication.

Also use  Policy Analyzer to  View recent usage for service accounts and keys

Use Activity Analyzer to see when your service accounts and keys were last used to call a Google API. These usages are called authentication activities.
Recent authentication activity can help you the identify service accounts and service account keys that you no longer use. We recommend disabling or deleting these unused service accounts and keys because they create an unnecessary security risk.
Note : This feature is subject to the "Pre-GA Offerings Terms" in the General Service Terms section of the Service Specific Terms. Pre-GA features are available "as is" and might have limited support. For more information, see the launch stage descriptions.


Thanks for the reply! I'm actually using the cloud monitoring metrics to see the different keys usage for a service account and I can see that different keys have been used by the SA. What I would like to know if I can see which key has been used by a cloud function/request

Seems that this isn't currently possible. There is also a feature request
to determine exactly when a Service Account key was used, along with the date and time of usage.

Sorry but I cannot access the link for the feature request...
I understand and that's a bummer. I received the same answer from their support.
Nevertheless, if you add this comment as an answer, I will accept it :)

My apologies for the incorrect link I provided earlier. Updated the answer,  Let me know if you still cannot access the link.

The answer depends on how the Cloud Function is authorized. Is the function requesting credentials from the metadata service or by a declared service account? IIRC, if by the metadata service, the request is made using a Google-managed service account signing key. That means none of your visible service account keys are used. Each service account has a hidden key used by Google for Google-managed activities on your behalf. Can you send this up to the IAM team to confirm?
